# Connection Closed error calling nodejs API on Azure

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure

I have a nodejs Rest API calling my on-prem SQL Server. It is hosted on Azure and connected to my SQL server using an Azure Hybrid Connection. All runs as expected on my local machine, but on Azure I'm getting a ConnectionClosed error (ECONNCLOSED) when I attempt to call the Test route below:

Here is my code sample:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

// Connection string parameters.
var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'restapi', //remove if using Windows Auth
    password: 'restapi', //remove if using Windows Auth
    database: 'dbname',
    server: 'server\\instance',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
}

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to the API"});
});

app.get('/Test', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query("select 1 as number")  //query
        .then(result => {
          let rows = result.recordset //first recordset
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          res.status(200).json(rows);
          sql.close();
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({
            message: err
          })
          sql.close();
        });
    })
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this by removing the driver & instance name from my sqlConfig:

```
var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'restapi', //remove if using Windows Auth
    password: 'restapi', //remove if using Windows Auth
    database: 'dbname',
    server: 'server',
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workable sample:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql');

var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'jack', 
    password: 'password',
    database: 'jackdemo',
    server: 'jackdemo.database.windows.net',
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
}

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to the API"});
});

app.get('/Test', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query("select 1 as number") 
        .then(result => {
          let rows = result.recordset //first recordset
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          res.status(200).json(rows);
          sql.close();
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send({
            message: err
          })
          sql.close();
        });
    })
});
```

You can also use the approach from the official tutorial: [Use Node.js to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs)

---

By the way, please ensure that you have correctly configure the firewall rule for you Azure SQL.  You need to add your client IP to the allowed list as: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#create-and-manage-ip-firewall-rules

Comment: My SQL server is on-prem. I am connecting to it through an Azure Hybrid Connection.